# FAA requirement for recording aircraft time

Tags: aircraft-certification

I am familiar with aircraft which use a Hobbs meter for timekeeping using an oil pressure switch.  I am also familiar with aircraft with a recording tachometer.

Less familiar are aircraft which use only a hobbs or similar timekeeping device.

What are the requirement for timekeeping on aircraft with a US airworthiness certificate?  Is there a part 23 or other requirement?

Comment: Does this answer your question (assuming you are asking about "time-in-service" for maintenance purposes): https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80039/what-are-the-differences-between-off-on-time-total-ac-time-and-offset

Comment: Some of the questions touch the topic, but I'm afraid none to date give a satisfactory citation.  Requirements are inferred, but the need for a timekeeping device is ambiguous.  As far as I have found, the requirements of FAR 91.409(b), as well as other requirements, could be met by fastidious manual timekeeping.